# While trying to find a topic or a queue, the specific JMS server requested could not be found

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I am trying to perform multiple concurrent listeners for JMS but I cannot connect to a queue.

My code looks like:

```xml
<bean id="messageListener-xxx" class="pl.sygnity.enea.sis.jms.SimpleMessageListener">
   <property name="initialContext" ref="xxxInitialContext" />
   <property name="jndiName" value="jms/xxx/LocationConnectionFactory" />
   <property name="queueName" value="xxx/Location/xxx/xxx" />
   <property name="isResponse" value="false" />
   <property name="messageId" value="xxxx" />
   <property name="encConvert" value="${jms.encConvert}" />
</bean>

<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="auto" concurrency="10-50">   
   <jms:listener destination="xxx/Location/xxx/xxx" ref="messageListener-xxx" method="onMessage" />    
</jms:listener-container>
```

When I run application a got warning like:

```
2020-04-27 15:45:04,778  WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-82] [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] [Line:882]: Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxx/Location/xxx/xxx' - trying to recover. Cause: [JMSExceptions:045103]While trying to find a topic or a queue, the specific JMS server requested could not be found. The linked exception may contain more information about the reason for failure. 
2020-04-27 15:45:05,282  INFO [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-82] [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] [Line:933]: Successfully refreshed JMS Connection 
2020-04-27 15:45:04,778  WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-82] [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] [Line:882]: Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxx/Location/xxx/xxx' - trying to recover. Cause: [JMSExceptions:045103]While trying to find a topic or a queue, the specific JMS server requested could not be found. The linked exception may contain more information about the reason for failure. 
2020-04-27 15:45:05,282  INFO [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-82] [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] [Line:933]: Successfully refreshed JMS Connection 
2020-04-27 15:45:04,778  WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-82] [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] [Line:882]: Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxx/Location/xxx/xxx' - trying to recover. Cause: [JMSExceptions:045103]While trying to find a topic or a queue, the specific JMS server requested could not be found. The linked exception may contain more information about the reason for failure. 
2020-04-27 15:45:05,282  INFO [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-82] [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] [Line:933]: Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

and it is continously refreshing and recovering again and again

What is `jms:listener` destination here? 
How can monitor newly creared concurrent threads?

Comment: The application output eventually says, "Successfully refreshed JMS Connection." Does that not indicate a successful connection?

Comment: Hmm.. yes, but this output is iterative, check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error .Here is how i resolved.
Use the correct name of topic and not the jNDI name( but the value of that JNDI):
@JmsListener(destination = ).
If you want to extract the value of JNDI use ctx.lookup("JNDI name here")

Answer (score -1):

The WebLogic Server instance on which that JMS server is targeted may be down. The JMS server may be suspended. Check on the status of the JMS server and also on the status of the communication between the servers in the cluster. Check the linked exception for more information about the cause of this failure.